# Events not being fired when running tests

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to test my store method for one of my models and the test is not dispatching the events making them fail.

```
public function store(StoreProject $request)
    {
        Log::info($request);
        $project = Project::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'created_by' => $request->created_by
        ]);

        //TODO email user about project

        event(new ProjectCreated($project));

        return $project;
    }
```

I have the ProjectCreated event that will be used to with some kind of socket service to notify others.

```
public function a_project_emits_a_project_created_event()
    {
        Event::fake();

        $this->signIn($user = factory(User::class)->create());

        $project = factory(Project::class)->make(['created_by' => $user->id]);
        $this->json('POST','/api/v1/projects',$project->toArray());

        Event::assertDispatched(ProjectCreated::class, function ($e) use ($project) {
            return $e->project->id === $project->id;
        });
    }
```

I am getting this error and not sure why since it should be true.

The expected [App\Events\ProjectCreated] event was not dispatched.
 ✖ Failed asserting that false is true.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$project` does not yet have an id because you are using `make()` this is not storing the model in the database.

You should catch the response from your api call and compare the id from the api returned `$project` instead of comparing to your factory made `$project`

Comment: I can't believe I did not see this. I tried to move events into my observer for the model and I get an error that the events are not being fired.